# Update workflows throughout an organisation

Tags: github, github-actions

I know that Github offers workflow templates to generate workflows in different repositories.

Assume now you have a standard workflow for e.g. a Java build and you created workflows from your "Java template" in 100 repositories.

Is there a good way to update these 100 workflows if something changes?

Of course, I could write a script that generates pull requests for all the repositories, but is there something more direct?

Comment: We looked for this recently in the organisation I work at, and we didn't find anything native. We ended up creating a script.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for the feedback. It is good to have some first hand experience. Could you roughly describe how your script works? That would be really helpful for me.

Comment: It's similar to what you said. First, we made a request to get all organization repositories, and ask to the script executor to choose which ones to update. Then we open a PR on each repository (using a loop calling the Github API for each repo) with the operation we want to perform. It's also possible to use a Github Actions workflow in each repository to auto-approve and auto-merge the PR if it comes from a specific user (through the user PAT sent with the Github API service to open the PR).